# if $a=\infty$ It can be concluded that ?: $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=0$

Tags: calculus

I know that if $f$ be odd function and $a,-a \in D_f$ Then :

$$\int_{-a}^af(x)=0$$

Now if $a=\infty$ It can be concluded that ?:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)=0$$

Answer (score 5):

No, the improper integral $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xdx$ does not exist.

Comment: Just a note to add on to this: This integral does not exist, but its [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value) is $0$, due to the fact that $$\lim_{a\to\infty} \int_{-a}^a f(x)\ dx = 0.$$